# why the minus and not in operator giving different result

Tags: sql

I have two tables tabA and TabB containg some ID's

I am doing

```
Select  DISTINCT ID from tabA minus select DISTINCT ID from TabB--- I am some ID's which do not exist in TabB.
```

But when I do

```
 Select DISTINCT Id from tabA where ID NOT IN (Select DISTINCT ID from TabB) ---------- I do not get any result
```

Answer (score 0):

NOT in fetches the record what ever is not available in the other table you are checking with. This is straight forward and easy to understand.

MINUS check the table you are using and it ignores matching and unmatching values and provides you the result. Use below link to understand more on MINUS

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `NOT IN` with subqueries!  It does not do the right thing if any returned values are `NULL`.  Well, it does the "right" thing -- it is just highly non-intuitive:  if *any* value is `NULL`, `NOT IN` filters out *all* rows.

So, you have discovered that `MINUS` treats `NULL`s one way and `NOT IN` a different way.

For this reason, I strongly advise that you use `NOT EXISTS`.

Note:  The `SELECT DISTINCT`s are redundant with `MINUS`.  That operator already removes duplicates (much like `UNION`).